# Python GUI application not working when double-clicking on executable

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to bundle my pyqt5 application using pyinstaller on ubuntu.
This application has been built in a virtual environnement, with pycharm as ide

**The app**

My application is a combination of 4 widgets windows :

- 1 home window that is displayed at the start of the application
- 3 form windows that I generate when pushing their respective button from the home window. They are not child widget of the home window

Plus I use qthreading to communicate with a local software on my machine and output its stdout into specific child widgets of the three forms (dropdown menus, lineEdit)
During the time when my worker is running a specific local software command and extracts its stdout, I display a modal dialog that shows some progression infos. This dialog is built into another worker associated to another thread.

**Creating binary file**

First I created my binary file using the pyinstaller command in my pycharm working directory :
`pyinstaller main.py`

Everything is working fine when I launch the file from the terminal : ***~\dir1...\dist\main***
I can switch between forms, threading works well, events handling is good, widgets actually receive data from my cli software

However when I launch the app by double-clicking on the binary file, the parts of my code that deal with
communicating with my local software do not work anymore. For example, my progression dialogsdon't render their content and are displayed in black except for their title bar.

I plan to use the double-clicking as the launching use case for end users.
Why do I get this inconsistent behaviour between running executable from terminal and double-clicking ? Is this just related to qt and its main loop event handling ?

Ubuntu version : 18.04.5
Python version : 3.8.14
Pyqt5 version : 5.15.7
Pyinstaller version : 5.4.1

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and also try to run the compiled binary from terminal to see if it provides some debug message.